# How do I get the Kind of Elements in an Array using Roslyn

Tags: vb.net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to get the Type that is iterated through using Roslyn. I can get the fact that the object is defined as String() using

```
  Dim ElementTypeInfo As TypeInfo = SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(ForEachStatement.Expression)
  Dim expressionType As ITypeSymbol = ElementTypeInfo.Type
```

and in the Visual Studio debugger I can look at expressionType.ElementType and find out it is a String. But when I try to access ElementType in code I get an error saying the ElementType is not a member of ITypeSymbol.

Comment: `Dim expressionType As ITypeSymbol` is where you're going wrong? If so, then don't declare it as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `expressionType` is going to be an array, you can cast it to `IArrayTypeSymbol`. After that, you will be able to access its `ElementType`:

```
Dim expressionType = DirectCast(elementTypeInfo.Type, IArrayTypeSymbol)
Dim elementType As ITypeSymbol = expressionType.ElementType
```